# Building with boost asio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, boost-asio

Im trying to build a project on Windows XP using Visual Studio 2010
using boost version 1.53.0 (which should matter, will explain)

erros are related to class in socket_option.hpp:

```
template <int Level, int Name>
class boolean
{
```

as i mentioned above, this class hasnt changed from first version of asio in boost 1.35.0

i get these errors:

```
D:\work\extern\include\boost/asio/detail/socket_option.hpp(34): error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
D:\work\extern\include\boost/asio/detail/socket_option.hpp(34): error C3306: 'boost::asio::detail::socket_option::': unnamed class template is not allowed
D:\work\extern\include\boost/asio/detail/socket_option.hpp(34): error C2628: 'boost::asio::detail::socket_option::' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
D:\work\extern\include\boost/asio/detail/socket_option.hpp(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
D:\work\extern\include\boost/asio/detail/socket_option.hpp(35): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

which also give alot more errors in usage of that class

Comment: Show your topsecret code

Comment: code is kinda big, problem is I dont get error reference to any of my code, all the errors come from socket_option.hpp, and all the usages of that boolean class, e.g. in socket_base.hpp, tcp.hpp etc.

Comment: I identified which object cause the errors .. if I exclude it from compilation it compiles successfuly,
weird thing is that that class have nothing to do with sockets, it doesnt even reference anything from that files, so I just changed include boost/asio.hpp to boost/asio/io_service.hpp (since i only need this one) and it works, but another weird thing is that another target that Im building is using those socket headers, and it compiles just fine with whole asio.hpp ..

Comment: See preprocessed code. I suspect you've got some macro that conflicts with asio code.

Comment: can you push me into right direction? I preprocessed problematic .cc file (its kinda huge, over 1kk lines, even though maybe 90% are empty lines), but anyway, if I search for "boolean" in it, i get only one occurence and even that is only a c-string as exception text, basicly I dont know what to search for, maybe it helps, but that problematic .cc file, in its header Im including Oracle oci.h, may that be cause of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are referencing the proper Boost includes.  This can be done from Visual Studio by selecting properties from the project menu or right clicking on your project from solution explorer and selecting properties.  Choose C/C++ and under additional include directories enter the path to where you installed Boost.  On my system where I am using Visual Studio 2008, I have Boost 1.52.0 installed under my C:\Program Files path.  So, this is what the setting looks like on my system:

C:\Program Files\boost_1_52_0\;

If you are using OpenSSL as well, then you will need to also specify the path to where you installed it.  On my system, it looks like this:

C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Win32Client\OpenSSL-Win32\include\;
C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Win32Client\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl\;

You will also need to specify the library path as well so that the linker will be able to build properly.  So, under the Properties dialog box, select Linker and under Additional Library Directories enter the path to the proper lib folder.  On my system it looks like:

C:\Program Files\boost_1_52_0\lib32\;

If using SSL, you will also need:

C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Win32Client\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static;

and

libeay32MDd.lib ssleay32MDd.lib

which is entered under the Linker / Inputs section.

I was not able to build with the 64 bit version of the OpenSSL libraries via Boost and have already submitted a bug report.  The 32 bit version builds fine though.

Comment: Thx, but that shouldnt be the problem, Im using CMake to generate whole VS solution, so I dont have to set anything in VS itself, but as I mentioned above in comments, I resolved it by using boost/asio/io_service.hpp instead of boost/asio.hpp